# Drop Down Menu That Opens All Drop Downs at Once

Tags: html, css, navigation, drop-down-menu

Is there a navigational drop down menu out there that when you hover over one item, every drop down comes down? I know it might be a bit busy, but for this project this is essential. It can use jQuery, just CSS or whatever, as long as it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you give all of the menus a class you can just select them all with jQuery.  Assuming they all are display:none;  any other show/hide attribute will work the same way.  The only issue is when you move your mouse away from one they all will go away.

```
$("#specialDropDown").live('mouseover',function(){
           $('.dropDown').css('display', 'block');
}); 

$(".drowDown").live('mouseout', function(){
          $('.dropDown').css('display','none');
});
```

The only issue is when you move your mouse away from one they all will go away.  To solve that I suggest having a button that shows them all.

```
$("#specialDropDown").live('click', function(){
         if($(this).hasClass('activeButton')
            {
               $(this).removeClass('activeButton');    
               $('.dropDown').css('display', 'none');
            }
        else
           {
               $(this).addClass('activeButton');    
               $('.dropDown').css('display', 'block');
             }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

No javascript required.

HTML:

```
<ul id='dropdowns'>
    <li>First menu
        <ul>...</ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#dropdowns ul { display: none }
#dropdowns:hover ul { display: block }
```

Everything else as with any other CSS dropdown. The only thing you'd need to do differently is show all menus when hovering over the outer dropdown container.